# T-SQL to HQL (NHibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have the following T-SQL:

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE UserId=@UserId
AND TableId NOT IN
(SELECT TOP 10 TableId
FROM Table
WHERE UserId=@UserId
ORDER BY DateColumn)
```

What is the NHibernate equivalent?

Comment: I don't think hql has `top` keyword...you need to use SetMaxResults() but I dunno how you could do that on the sub-query. Maybe break into two separate queries?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when modifying multiple elements in NHibernate I would use **HQL**.

You could also firs querying the inner select, so you would get 10 id's. And then use where tableId not in (1, 2, 3, 4th id, etc...)